# "Error: void value not ignored as it ought to be" - Understanding the error and trying to overcome it

Tags: c++, c++11

Following is my code snippet.The error occurs in the `display_results()` method.

```
    class results
    {
    public:
        bool majority;
        int major_element = 0;

    void show_results()
        {
            if (majority)
            {
                cout<<"Majority found "<<major_element;
            }

            else
                cout<<"No majority element found";
        }
    };
void display_results(results* p, int number_of_testcases)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<number_of_testcases;i++)
        {
          //Error occurs in next line  
         *p[i].show_results();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain me why is this happening?

Comment: The asterisk in *p[i].show_results() should be removed, i.e. it should be:  p[i].show_results().  With the asterisk you are trying to dereference the value returned by show_results(), but show_results() returns void and dereferencing a void doesn't make any sense, hence the error message.

Comment: `p[i].show_results()` returns `void` - that is, no value. You are then, inexplicably, trying to dereference that nothing with a star `*`. Drop that.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner for clearing my doubt!

Comment: If you're using C++, esp 11, there is no reason to ever write code this way though. Pass a vector by const ref.